# Fourier Transform: $x(t)=2\sin(2\omega_0t)\cos(3\omega_0t)$

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, linear-systems, fourier

I'm currently studying Fourier Transforms and do not understand the Fourier Transform of $x(t)=2\sin(2\omega_0t)\cos(3\omega_0t)$

My solution states that it is

$X(\omega)=\frac{2}{2\pi}(-j\pi[\delta_0(\omega-2\omega_0)-\delta_0(\omega+2\omega_0)])*\pi[\delta_0(\omega-3\omega_0)+\delta_0(\omega+3\omega_0)]$

My try:

$x(t)=2\sin(2\omega_0t)\cos(3\omega_0t)$

Using multiplication rule, transform sin and cos

$X(\omega)=\frac{2}{2\pi}(\frac{\pi}{j}[\delta_0(\omega-2\omega_0)-\delta_0(\omega+2\omega_0)])*\pi[\delta_0(\omega-3\omega_0)+\delta_0(\omega+3\omega_0)]$

My question is:  Why is in the transform for sin $-j\pi$ and not $\frac{\pi}{j}$?

Comment: 1/j =-j, so they are the same

Comment: Another question. Why does the solution stop with the dirac impulses? I thought that the Fourier Transform has consist of $e^{j\omega t}$?

Comment: @Rapiz, The Fourier transform is the integration of the function multiplied by the complex exponential. The dirac delta has an identity, $\delta(\omega-\omega_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{(-jt(\omega-\omega_0))}dt$, which can be used in this problem by converting sines and cosines into their [exponential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry).

Comment: Your $x(t)$ the way you have written it, is a _constant_ since there is no $t$ on the right hand side. This makes all your calculations nonsensical. Please edit you question appropriately. -1 pending edits.

Comment: I have removed my downvote since you have made an effort to edit the question and @PeterK.'s edits have cleaned up the remaining typos. I will point out that using the rule that the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms of the individual terms leads to a _convolution of impulses_ that requires further work to get to a usable answer. Far better to use $$x(t)=2\sin(2\omega_0t)\cos(3\omega_0t) = \sin(5\omega_0t)-\sin(\omega_0t)$$ to find $X(\omega)$ without any need for further calculations. But your grader/instructor going by the book will likely disagree.